# H2OAutoEncoderEstimator Anomaly Prediction REST API

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, predictive, h2o4gpu

I am creating H2o Autoencoder Anomaly Detection model in h2o python.When calculating anomalies using (test_rec_error=model.anomaly(test.hex,per_feature=false) I am getting one reconstruction error for each record.But When I am trying to predict(finding anomaly) on any test data in H2o Flow I am getting reconstruction error per feature.Is there any option in h2o Flow to get only one reconstruction error(not per feature) in h2o flow?

Also what is the REST API endpoint for getting reconstruction error from anomaly model in h2o. Just like for scoring prediction on test data in classification models API(POST /3/Predictions/models/{model}/frames/{frame}) is there..So just wanted to know whats the REST API for getting reconstruction error from anomaly model in h2o.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please suggest...